# Quotient space is connected...

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\sim$ be an equivalence relation defined on it.  Let $Y$ be the space $X/{\sim}$ and $p :X \rightarrow Y $ be the quotient map, and give $Y$ the quotient topology.  If $Y$ is connected, must $X$ be connected as well?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not necessarily. Let $X$ be a non-connected space and let $\sim$ be the equivalence such that $X$ itself is the
only equivalence class (equivalently $p$ is constant). Then $Y$ is a singleton, hence connected,
but $X$ is not.

Comment: Ohhhhh!! That's really a beautiful trick!! Most elegant counterexample I was looking for!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to think about what condition you want the fibers of the projection satisfy.

Comment: Fibers should be connected.... I mean.. I think there I am getting stucked!!Isn't it??

Comment: Yes, if you suppose that fibers are connected then the answer is affirmative (prove it), otherwise, @drhab provided a nice and easy counterexample.

Comment: Yes Yes!! Assuming that fibers are connected, $X$ is also connected!! So.. in the condition it should be there that for each $y$ ,$p^{-1} (y)$ is connected; to prove that $X$ is connected!!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine two identical, disjoint, infinitely thin, circular pancakes. Imagine gluing them together by their faces. Think about what your initial object is, what your final object is, and what the process is, as analogies of stuff from topology. I hope this helps.